# Numpy transpose data in example

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, reshape

So I'm finding this hard to visualise but essentially I've read in some data using numpy (python3.x) with

```
 np.genfromtext()
```

which gives me a 3d array of shape (5, 1024, 2). Essentially 5 arrays, each of 1024 coordinate pairs.

What I'm doing is shifting each of the x coordinates along by 21.0 to normalise my data, and I then want to write it all back to a new files in the same format as before (before I had 5 separate files of coordinate pairs followed by linebreaks), ie

```
x0 y0 
x1 y1
x2 y2 (this x 1024)
```

This is proving harder than I'd thought, and at the moment the best I can do extract each, shift each in a for loop by 21 and put it back together, but when I do this, I get it to be the shape (5, 2, 1024) which is not the same. I need this to be reshaped to (5, 1024, 2) but I don't understand how reshape works.

If anybody fancies a challenge, I then need to write each of the 5 sets of coordinate pairs to separates files.

Thanks.

Comment: Say `a` is your array , to shift all x by 21 is as simple as `a[:,:,0]+=21`. As you mention using a for-loop I assume this is not the way you're doing it. If my assumption is correct I stronly suggest reading a basic numpy tutorial to learn the main numpy "tricks".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer the question :

What you want is actualy a **transposition** (ie swapping the position of two axes) not a reshape. To transpose (5,2,1024) to (5,1024,2) you can use the following :

```
a = np.random.rand(5,2,1024)

b = np.transpose(a,[0,2,1])
print(a.shape)
print(b.shape)
```